# Results not being returned for MongoDB query in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I am not getting any results returned from the database when accessing the PHP file directly, however all the `echo` checks below are returning expected results.

This is entire PHP file.

```
<?php 

$ext = new ReflectionExtension('mongo');  // see http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionextension.getversion.php
var_dump($ext->getVersion());  // returns string(5) "1.3.4"

echo extension_loaded("mongo") ? "loaded<br />" : "not loaded<br />";  // check if driver installed - returns "loaded"

$dbhost = '127.x.xx.x';
$dbname = 'mydb';
$m = new Mongo("mongodb://$dbhost");  // also tried 'MongoClient' rather than 'Mongo'
if ($m == true) {
echo "<br />connected to {$m}<br />";  // returns "connected to 127.x.xx.x:27017
}
$db = $m->$dbname;
$collection = $db->myCollection;
echo "<br />my collection is called {$collection}<br />";  // returns "my collection is called mydb.myCollection"
$query = $collection->find();
if ($query == true) {
echo "<br />the find method works";  // this is being returned
}
foreach($query as $result) { // nothing is happening here
var_dump($result);
}

?>
```

Command line query for:

```
db.myCollection.find();
```

is returning expected results (there is one document).

Comment: What does it mean *directly*? Do you mean by making a request to the *.php file?

Comment: I mean when going to the PHP file directly in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

Adjust above code to:

```
$dbhost = 'username:password@127.x.xx.x:27017/';
$dbname = 'yourdbname';
$m = new MongoClient("mongodb://$dbhost");
```

In my case I needed to define IP address.

Answer (score 0):

What version of PECL mongo lib are you using? if >= 1.3.0 (we are now on 1.4.3 stable), the `Mongo` class is deprecated and you are encouraged to use `MongoClient` instead. 
Please refer to [phpDoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongo.php).

Comment: How can I see what version of PECL mongo lib is being used?

Comment: Maybe you use [this](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionextension.getversion.php) ?

Comment: following http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-php-mongodb-mongo-driver-on-linux-mac-os-x-windows-unix-bsd/ , `pecl search mongo` returns `mongo 1.4.3 (stable) MongoDB database driver`, then I ran `pecl install mongo`.  i cannot follow the rest of the steps on the above URL because i don't have write permission on php.ini it seems.  result of `ReflectionExtension::getVersion` on `mongo` is now `string(5) "1.3.4"`. have changed to `MongoClient` and no results.